# Scope does not update values from script to html

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

I'm new at trying angularjs and eclipse and i have written the html and corresponding javascript but the scope does not update values from script to html. What could be the possible problem?

---

### My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="Login.js"></script>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    first name : {{name.firstname}}
    last name : {{name.lastname}}
    10+20 = {{ 10+20 }}
  </body>
</html>
```

### my js file

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl",function($scope) 
{
    var name = {
            firstname : "john",
            lastname : "david"
    }
    $scope.name=name;
});
```

Comment: `name` does not change once initialized, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Did you load your MyCtrl file?

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: there are no errors or warnings shown, nor are the values set for first name and last name updated when run on browser.

Comment: see **[this](https://plnkr.co/edit/pJFhvi8Gdqbqthri0ReL?p=preview)** plunker, your code works fine...

Comment: Yes it does here. Then there must be an issue with the server connections. I'll check it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   var name = {
            firstname : "john",
            lastname : "david"
    }
    $scope.name=name;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS </title>
    <script src="app.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    first name : {{name.firstname}}
    last name : {{name.lastname}}
    10+20 = {{ 10+20 }}
  </body>

</html>
```